# Use WebSecurityConfiguration because WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter option no more supported, stuck in Circular Reference instead

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, ubuntu, spring-security

so I create this simple login system application by using Java Spring Boot and use Spring Security for authentication.

This is spec of the application:

- spring tool suite 4.18.0.RELEASE
- spring security 6
- using java 17
- built on top linux ubuntu 22.04
- thymeleaf
- `application.properties` is already located in `resource` folder by default in `SBTLEmpManSys/src/main/resources`
- I package this works into executable jar file by using maven build feature given by STS (spring tool suite)

When I want to use `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` for my `SecurityConfiguration.java` the IDE did not offer the option. It offer `WebSecurityConfiguration` instead so I use it. Turn out it gives circular reference.

This is the diagram:

```
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  securityConfiguration (field private org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity)
↑     ↓
|  org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/HttpSecurityConfiguration.class]
└─────┘
```

I handle this problem by setting `spring.main.allow-circular-reference=true` in `application.properties` for temporary solution to complete my work. But this problem will reappear in executable .jar file

On the other hand, I need this security configuration file to provide `BCryptPasswordEncoder` for my service implementation file `EmpServiceImpl.java`.

I have tried to use `@Lazy` here and there but there is no effect. I also tried figure out solution for this problem through google & this forum but still can not solve it.

Does anyone can help? This is really give me a headache.

Here are my files.

This is the security configuration

```
package com.kastamer.sbtl.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.kastamer.sbtl.service.EmpService;

@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfiguration {

//  public EmpService empService;
    
//  @Lazy --> NO EFFECT
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
//  @Lazy --> NO EFFECT
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManBuild = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests.requestMatchers(
                "/registrasi",
                "/js**",
                "/css**",
                "/img**")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
        .formLogin((form) -> form.loginPage("/login").permitAll())
        .logout((logout) -> logout.invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true).logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").permitAll());
        
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

This is the service implementation:

```
package com.kastamer.sbtl.service;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.kastamer.sbtl.model.EmpRole;
import com.kastamer.sbtl.model.Employee;
import com.kastamer.sbtl.repository.EmployeeRepository;
import com.kastamer.sbtl.web.dto.EmpRegistrationDTO;

@Service
public class EmpServiceImpl implements EmpService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository empRepDAO;
    
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    //@Autowired //THIS is ADDITION to AVOID CIRCULAR REFERENCE --> ANNOTATION NO EFFECT
    //public EmpServiceImpl(@Lazy EmployeeRepository empRepDAO) { //ANNOTATION '@Lazy' is ADDITION to AVOID CIRCULAR REFERENCE --> ANNOTATION NO EFFECT
    public EmpServiceImpl(EmployeeRepository empRepDAO) {
        super();
        this.empRepDAO = empRepDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Employee pegawai = empRepDAO.findByEmail(username);
        
        if (pegawai == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Email atau kata sandi tidak cocok!");
        }
        
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(pegawai.getEmail(), pegawai.getPassword(), mapRolesToAuthority(pegawai.getRoles())); //return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Employee save(EmpRegistrationDTO empRegistrationDTO) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Employee karyawan = new Employee(
                empRegistrationDTO.getFullName(),
                empRegistrationDTO.getEmail(),
                passwordEncoder.encode(empRegistrationDTO.getPassword()),
                Arrays.asList(new EmpRole("ROLE_USER")));
        
        return empRepDAO.save(karyawan); //return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void simpanPembaruanData(Employee employee) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        employee.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(employee.getPassword()));
        
        this.empRepDAO.save(employee);
    }
    
    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapRolesToAuthority(Collection<EmpRole> roles) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return roles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getNamaRole())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    //PART POJOK KARYAWAN
    @Override
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return empRepDAO.findAll(); //return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Employee getEmployeeById(long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Optional<Employee> optEmp = empRepDAO.findById(id);
        Employee empl = null;
        
        if (optEmp.isPresent()) {
            empl = optEmp.get();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Karyawan dengan emp_id '" + id + "' tidak bisa ditemukan");
        }
        
        return empl; //return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEmployeeById(long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.empRepDAO.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Page<Employee> findPaginated(int pageNo, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortAscOrDesc) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Sort runut = sortAscOrDesc.equalsIgnoreCase(Sort.Direction.ASC.name()) ? Sort.by(sortField).ascending() : Sort.by(sortField).descending();
        
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo - 1, pageSize, runut);
        
        return this.empRepDAO.findAll(pageable); //return null;
    }
}
```

This is the application.properties

```
# DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myDB
spring.datasource.username=[POSTGRES_LOGIN]
spring.datasource.password=[POSTGRES_PASSWORD]
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

# The PostgreSQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better Postgresql for the chosen databse
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update, none --> 'default')
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

# Prepare logging-time system for Spring-Boot engine & will print logs in console (also work as work-level to monitor generated HQL in console)
logging.level.org.hibernate.sql=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace
#spring.jpa.show-sql=true

# Default user login and password for spring security web login page (if spring security is enabled)
#spring.security.user.name=spring
#spring.security.user.password=spring123 
#spring.security.user.roles=USER

spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
#spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can break the cycle by making the factory method of the password encoder static:

```
@Bean
public static BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Then the creation of the password encoder no longer depends on an instance of the configuration class being instantiated.

Comment: I have put `static` but still trapped in circular reference